# Cleaning up labeled image with mouse clicks (numpy, matplotlib)

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have an image that has been segmented and labeled, and I'd now like to clean up the labeled image by clicking on labels that I'd like to delete.
So far I can read the coordinates and select the label that I want to delete, but I'm unsure how to update the plot. 
Right now the script makes a new window with each click, and only allows me to delete one label.

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = np.array([
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 0, 4, 4, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]
])

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(im)

def onclick(event):
    global im
    row, col = (int(event.ydata + 0.5)), (int(event.xdata + 0.5))
    print(row, col)

    label_to_delete = im[row, col]

    im = np.where(im == label_to_delete, 0, im)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots()
    axes.imshow(im)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need making a new figure and axes every event. Secondly, you need to call `pause`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.imshow(im)

def onclick(event):
    global im
    row, col = (int(event.ydata + 0.5)), (int(event.xdata + 0.5))
    print(row, col)

    label_to_delete = im[row, col]
    im = np.where(im == label_to_delete, 0, im)
    axes.imshow(im)
    plt.pause(0.05)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```